# Tweedie distribution GLM for manyany() in {mvabund} package

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis

My data follow a Tweedie distribution, and I'm working with multivariate abundances. So I'm trying to use the `manyany()` function in the `mvabund` package. `manyany()` fits many univariate models to multivariate abundance data, in this case I'm trying to fit Generalized Linear Models (GLMs).

Using the example data set in `mvabund`, I've given my code below. Although the example data set is Poisson distributed, the same error message appears for my own data set as it does for the example below.

```
data(spider)
abund <- spider$abund
X <- as.matrix(spider$x)

## To fit a log-linear model assuming counts are poisson:
spidPois <- manyany("glm",abund,data=X,abund~X,family=poisson())

## Fitting tweedie GLMs, error message given. 
spidTwee <- manyany("glm",abund,data=X,abund~X,family=tweedie(var.power=1.2))

## Error in if (xi != power) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I set the `var.power=1.2` because a value of 1 would be a Poisson. When looking at the command `rtweedie()` I noticed that `xi` is said to be a synonym for power. I'm stuck now though and unsure where to go from here.

One option would be to just use a negative binomial GLM, which I've tried and it works fine. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/can-a-negative-binomial-distribution-be-used-to-model-a-continuous-distribution) answer indicates that a Tweedie would be better, but I guess an extension would be how to determine how poorly a negative binomial GLM would be fitting your data.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

### Update:

I tried using `gam()` with `manyany()`, specifically with the Tweedie using `tw()`, as recommended.

```
library(mgcv)
gam <- mgcv::gam
tw <- mgcv::tw
spidTweeGAM <- manyany("gam", abund, data = X, abund~X, family=tw())

#### Error in manyany("gam", abund, data = X, abund ~ X, family = tw()) : 
  family argument has length more than one but not equal to the number of columns in yMat (!?)
```

I don't really know how to interpret this error message though! Again, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer. When you use `manyany` with a Tweedie distribution, there is an argument within the `tweedie()` function, but you also have to specify the `var.power` parameter in the `manyany` function.

> spidTwee <-
>   manyany("glm", abund, data=X, abund~X, family = tweedie(var.power=1.2), var.power=1.2)

Answer (score 1):

You could do a `manyany()` using `gam()` from package **mgcv**. From version 1.8-0 this has had a `tw()` family function (so you use it as `family = tw` etc). This will also do a search for the Tweedie parameter as part of the model fitting (I suppose this is your `var.power`) so you don't even need to state this value or assume it is the same for all species.

The same package has an `nb` family function for the negative binomial distribution with search for $\theta$, so you don't need to specify this either. You could assess the relative fitness of the two approaches using prediction error (MSE or RMSE) for example either on hold-out data or in a cross-validation process.

Comment: I'd like to use a GLM rather than a GAM, do you know of a similar approach using GLMs?

Comment: A GAM as per mgcv is a penalised GLM; try it with `gam()` but just don't include any smooth terms (for a single species) and see if it works. I think `gam()` is OK without having any smooth terms at all in the model, in which case it is just a GLM.